# How to edit header of tar.gz file that has been split

Tags: tar, gzip

I downloaded a tar.gz file which is approx 50gb, and it is part of a larger tar.gz file that is 500gb that was split up into ten 50gb sections. When I try and decompress the 50gb file, I get an "unexpected end of file error" because I'm trying to decompress a single section of the file. However I dont want to download all 10 files and then concatenate them together, so I wondering if it is possible to edit the header of the separate files to reflect their actual individual sizes?

Answer (score 0):

No. The `tar` header is in the beginning of the 1st section. you will have to download and reassemble the file, at least up to the section you want.
See https://www.fileformat.info/format/tar/corion.htm . Adding `gzip` compression makes the file harder to uncompress in the middle.